# List. Конструктор копирования.

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::list<std::string> name;
public:
    MyClass(void);
    void add(std::string name); //добавляет в список
    ~MyClass(void);
};
```

Как сделать конструктор копирования? Нужен ли конструктор копирования при использовании list, vector, array и т.д (мне кажется, что нужен)

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае не нужен.

Comment: а если класс будут наследовать или создать несколько экземпляров этого класса (MyClass mc1, mc2)? А когда нужен будет?

Comment: @miyu: очевидно же — конструктор копирования нужен тогда, когда конструктор копирования по умолчанию не подходит. Например, если у вас есть указатели в членах класса.

Comment: я бы в большинстве случаев, которые являются контейнерами запрещал копирование совсем. При передаче куда либо использовал бы ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Копирующий конструктор будет создан компилятором. Такой копирующий конструктор по-умолчанию для каждого члена вызывает конструкторы копирования. В данном случае это именно то поведение, которое требуется.

В свете C++11 лучше указать это явно:

```
MyClass(const MyClass&) = default;
```